# HTML 5 & Javascript Drag and drop on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get Drag and Drop using only Javascript and HTML 5 on IE 9 and 8 (or at least IE 9) but it wont work and I have read drag and drop should work on IE. Can you have a look at my code and help me out to get this to work with IE?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
    var drag = ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var image= ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
    if ( image == ev.target.id) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

    }

    else {

    }
}
</script>
<section id="planetBox">
<img class="planetImage" id="mercuryImg" draggable="true" 
    ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="A Planet" src="./images/planets/mercury.gif">  
</section>  

<div class="planet">
<section class="venusBox" id="venusImg" ondrop="drop(event)" 
    ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></section>
<section class="planetName"><h3>Venus</h3></section>    
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried your code in any other browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
var drag = ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
var image= ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
```

to

```
var drag = ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
var image= ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
```

and you might look at removing that if condition

```
if ( image == ev.target.id) {
```